# FK and M2M realtions in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I use fk and m2m relations in magento?
I read about EAV and I understand the benefits
but I don't understand how to approach common problems in relational databases.

For example, I have products that should match several type of cars.
Each car has make,model,year.
With regular tables I'll have a Car table and I'll have m2m relation from each product to this table. Then, I can filter by car and reference the user's car in the order.

How can I implement cars and relate them to products in magento
and how can I save the user's car in the order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom DB table and manage the m2m relation myself.

Answer (score 4):

The ORM Provided by Magento's Framework does not support many to many relationships.  If you need to provide this type of functionality for additional Magento functionality  you'll need to use a different ORM system, or write your SQL queries manually.

If you want to stick to the Magento core files, I'd investigate the Zend_Db* files that come bundled in lib.

Remember, while there's a lot of cool Framework features in Magento, it wasn't built to be a general purpose development framework.  It was built to service the needs of Varien/Magento Inc in building an Ecommerce Platform.

Comment: Magento has configurable products. Several configurable products can reference several Simple Products. Isn't that a m2m relation?
Can I use Zend_Db and create my own table? How can I point the product to a row in my table?

Comment: 1. I'm not super familiar with the object hierarchy behind configurable products, but one configurable product references many simple products.  I'm pretty sure Simple product objects don't have a reference to any configurable product they're a part of, so that's a 1 to Many relationship.  I could be wrong on that.  If you find out something different be sure to let the community know!

Comment: 1 to many relationship is a good start. How do I create it? Can I have relationship to a custom table?

Comment: Hey Alan. You're correct on there being no m2m relationship code builpt in, but configurable products are many-to-many (a simple product can belong to many configurable products). See the table catalog_product_super_link.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the correction.  Good to know they're keeping track of the relationship properly!