# Magento Collections and Many to Many relationships & crud

Tags: php, collections, magento, many-to-many, crud

I haven't found a very convenient way of making a collection from a many to many relationship.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call the toArray() method and end up with something like:

```
id => 1,
value_field => array('foo','bar')

id => 2, 
value_filed => array('baz', 'qux')
```

..

To complicate this,  i'd like to be able to load this many to many relationship into a backend CRUD and on save, update the proper values in the linkage table.

I'm currently thinking about using an afterLoad and afterSave to build and save the collection / POSTed data, but I've seen this done in a more pratical/automagic way in other frameworks an cant see that Magento hasn't handled this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: and in what framework this is handled better than in zend framework?

Comment: I should more correctly say that I'm not sure how it's suppose to be done in Magento/Zend Framework, so I cant compare it to what I've seen elsewhere.  I am a having a bit of a hard time understanding what the relationship of Magento's Database layer is to Zend Framework's Database layer, and what that means to me.  Particulary I was talking about CakePHP.  I can bind models to each other and if I do a save, the save respects the relationship.  I edited my question to word in better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(No) answer here: [FK and M2M realtions in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216616/fk-and-m2m-realtions-in-magento)  thanks to Alan Storm.